# Why isn't the expected function called? Do I understand type traits incorrectly?

Tags: c++, type-traits

I am trying to learn the concept of type traits. And I wrote some code to test my understanding:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <utility>

class Normal1 {};
class Normal2 {};
class Special {};

struct Normal_tag {};
struct Special_tag {};

template <typename T>
struct trait {
    typedef Normal_tag Type;
};

template <>
struct trait<Special> {
    typedef Special_tag Type;
};

template <typename T>
void handle_impl(T&& object, Normal_tag) {
    std::cout << "normal called\n";
}

template <typename T>
void handle_impl(T&& object, Special_tag) {
    std::cout << "special called\n";
}

// method 1: can't pass in rvalue
// template <typename T>
// void handle(T& object) {
//     handle_impl(object, typename trait<T>::Type());
//     std::cout << '\t' << typeid(T).name()                       << '\n'
//               << '\t' << typeid(typename trait<T>::Type).name() << '\n';
// }

// method 2: always lvalue
// template <typename T>
// void handle(const T& object) {
//     handle_impl(object, typename trait<T>::Type());
//     std::cout << '\t' << typeid(T).name()                       << '\n'
//               << '\t' << typeid(typename trait<T>::Type).name() << '\n';
// }

// method 3: try to use universal reference
template <typename T>
void handle(T&& object) {
    // handle_impl(object, typename trait<T>::Type());
    handle_impl(std::forward<T>(object), typename trait<T>::Type());
    std::cout << '\t' << typeid(T).name()                       << '\n'
              << '\t' << typeid(typename trait<T>::Type).name() << '\n';
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Normal1 n1;
    Normal2 n2;
    Special sp;

    handle(sp);                 // This line
    handle(n1);
    handle(n2);

    handle(Special());
    handle(Normal1());
    handle(Normal2());

    return 0;
}
```

The output below is not what I expected, I want the special method to be call for both lvalue and rvalue arguments:

```
normal called
        7Special
        10Normal_tag
normal called
        7Normal1
        10Normal_tag
normal called
        7Normal2
        10Normal_tag
special called
        7Special
        11Special_tag
normal called
        7Normal1
        10Normal_tag
normal called
        7Normal2
        10Normal_tag
```

I think the output means that the class `Special` is used for instantiation. But why do I get `Normal_tag`? Why is the call `handle(sp);` behaving this way?

I was hoping the universal reference will take care of both lvalue and rvalue argument, is this a bad way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call `handle(sp);` *sp* is L-value, so in your `handle` template `T` is deduced to be `Special&` but you don't have specialization for `Special&`

```
template <>
struct trait<Special&> {
   typedef Special_tag Type;
};
```

therefore you got *normal called* as output.

Comment: Or use `std::remove_reference_t<T>`

Comment: Then I think `handle(Special());` will make `T` be deduced to `Special&&`, why don't I need a specialization for `Special&&`?

Comment: @Killzone Kid Do you mean like `handle_impl(std::forward<T>(object), typename trait<std::remove_reference<T>>::Type());`? Seems don't work.

Comment: @fengqi When you pass Rvalue `T` is deduced to be `T` not `T&&`. While calling `handle(Special());` you are passing Rvalue so `T` is `Special`, while instatiating `handle` template you have signature `handle(Special&& object)` and inside code `trait<Special>::Type()`. When you pass Lvalue `T` is deduced to be `Special&` and signature of handle is `handle(Special& && object)` - >after collapsing references you got `handle(Special& object)` and `trait<Special&>::Type()`.